# checking for any occurrence of special characters with jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

If I have a set of special characters like: `!@#$%^&*(){}[]<>?/|-` how could I check for existence of any of these in a string ( or field value)? Trying to add a method jQuery validator plugin that would reject the field if any of them are present. I realize this is asking for a lot, regex is just killing me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
/[!@#$%\^&*(){}[\]<>?/|\-]/
```

You only need to escape the `]`.  Inside a character class (`[]`), the other characters are interpreted literally.

More info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html (Under "Metacharacters Inside Character Classes")

Comment: @TheMask: You *can* escape the other control characters, but you shouldn't have to.  `^` only means "not" when it's at the beginning of a character class, and `-` only means "thru" when there's a character before and after it, like `[a-d]`.  `]` means "end of character class", so it needs to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks. I have removed my answer because is only a duplicated answer. :)

Comment: ... doesn't the '/' from the left have to be escaped like '\/'

Comment: @vector: It seemed to work just fine only escaping the `]`.  Inside `[]`, special characters seem to behave differently.

Comment: ... twas blowin' up for me, seems to work when that slash is escaped

Comment: @vector: Oh, ok.  It seemed to work for me.  Glad you got it working :-)

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat what if characters like ☺■☻♣♦♠☼♫♪↕§ these appears on my copied text and I want to validate this on pasting to a text field.

Comment: @tvshajeer: I've never really messed with regex and weird unicode characters.