# jQuery: Check if special characters exists in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters

I know this question is asked more often here on Stack, but I can't seem to get a straight answer out of the questions already posted.

I need to check if all special characters (except -) are in a string, if so, then give the user an alert.

What I have so far is this:

```
if($('#Search').val().indexOf('@') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('#') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('$') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('%') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('^') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('&') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('*') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('(') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf(')') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('_') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('\'') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('\"') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('\\') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('|') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('?') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('/') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf(':') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf(';') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('!') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('~') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('`') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf(',') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('.') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('<') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('>') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('{') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('}') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('[') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf(']') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('+') == -1 || $('#Search').val().indexOf('=') == -1)
{
   // Code that needs to execute when none of the above is in the string
}
else
{
  alert('Your search string contains illegal characters.');
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me on this matter?

Comment: You need to use a regular expression here instead of a bazillion separate conditions. And you **definitely** have to say how exactly it "doesn't seem to work".

Comment: See this may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505772/checking-for-any-occurrence-of-special-characters-with-jquery

Answer (score 100, accepted):

If you really want to check for all those special characters, it's easier to use a regular expression:

```
var str = $('#Search').val();
if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(str) == false) {
    alert('Your search string contains illegal characters.');
}
```

The above will only allow strings consisting entirely of characters on the ranges `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, plus the hyphen an space characters. A string containing any other character will cause the `alert`.

Comment: Added a short explanation. The downside is that it won't allow international characters like `é` and `ñ`, but if you don't need to allow them I believe it's the way to go.

Comment: It works, even with the international characters ;) Thanks again!

Comment: This fails for international characters (chinese, arabic etc). I wouldn't use it. It doesn't look for special characters like anton's example.

Comment: Why don't we write `/[^a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/` instead of `/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/`?

Comment: @Stallman The meaning is different. Inside the brackets, the `^` negates the list instead of defining the beginning of the string.

Comment: @bfavaretto what if characters like ☺■☻♣♦♠☼♫♪↕§ these appears on my copied text and I want to validate this on pasting to a text field

Comment: It seems this example doesn't invalidate whitespace. To do so, use /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/

Answer (score 23):

```
var specialChars = "<>@!#$%^&*()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\,./~`-="
var check = function(string){
    for(i = 0; i < specialChars.length;i++){
        if(string.indexOf(specialChars[i]) > -1){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if(check($('#Search').val()) == false){
    // Code that needs to execute when none of the above is in the string
}else{
    alert('Your search string contains illegal characters.');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also use the whitelist method -

```
var str = $('#Search').val();
var regex = /[^\w\s]/gi;

if(regex.test(str) == true) {
    alert('Your search string contains illegal characters.');
}
```

The regex in this example is digits, word characters, underscores (\w) and whitespace (\s). The caret (^) indicates that we are to look for everything that is not in our regex, so look for things that are not word characters, underscores, digits and whitespace.

Comment: This fails for international characters(chinese, arabic etc).I wouldn't use it.

Comment: `== true`? Wouldn't `if(regex.test(str)) { [...] }` suffice?

Comment: Of course it would @scniro. I just put the entire equation for clarity sake.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking whether the string contains *all* illegal characters. Change the `||`s to `&&`s.