# Validate username as the user types with jQuery and ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I want to validate a username as the user is typing according. The validation requirements are:

1. no whitespace;
2. no special characters;
3. within a defined minimum and maximum length; and
4. not the same as an existing username.

How do I do this using jQuery and ASP.NET?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: barvo! I understood the question, may I ask what has been tried so far to achieve this

Comment: yes, i have done this manually for points 1-It should not contain space, 3-It should have minimum & maximum length, 4-Is should not be duplicate / existing username

Comment: but not able to achieve 2nd point

Comment: @NikhilChavan see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840143/jquery-check-if-special-characters-exists-in-string) for point 2.

Comment: @James, thank bro, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input[type=textbox]").keydown(function(){
    if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test($(this).val()) == false) {
        alert('Your search string contains illegal characters.');
    }
    if(/\s/g.test($(this).val()) {
        alert("has white-space");
    }
    if(!$(this).val().length >= 8 && !$(this).val().length <= 25) {
        alert("out of range");
    }
});
```

For the fourth one you need to do it yourself because I don't have access to your field names etc.