# check if a string only has punctuation in it in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, punctuation

In an if statement, I want to check if the string has punctuation in it. If it has punctuation, I want an alert message to pop up.

```
if((/*regex presumably*/.test(rspace))==true||(/*regex presumably*/.test(sspace))==true){
    alert('Please enter your guessed answer in the fields provided, without punctuation marks.');

    //if only punctuation are entered by the user, an alert message tells them to enter something.
}
```

Do I need a regex, or is there an automatic method to do this for me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13840211/3894168

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *need* regex, but that would probably be simplest. It's a straight forward character class, put the characters you want to disallow inside `[...]`, e.g.:

```
if (/[,.?\-]/.test(rspace)) {
    // ....
}
```

Note that within `[]`, `-` is special, so if you want to include it put a backslash before it (as above). Same with backslash, come to that.

---

Note that you never need to write `== true` in a condition. You can if you want, but it serves no purpose from the JavaScript engine's perspective.

Comment: what about [] or {} or ()? Are they special too?

Comment: @StephenGevanni: Easiest thing to do is to check some documentation. [The spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.5) is pretty hard to read, but [MDN's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is pretty good. Only one of the characters in your list is special inside a character class: `]` (as it ends the class). None of the others are. The others are special *outside* a character class, though.