# My regex javascript validation doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate a textbox to see if it contains numbers and special characters, but for some reason, my code doesn't seem to work:

```
<script>
    function validation(){
        var firstname = $("#Fname").val();
        if(firstname.match(/^[A-Za-z]*/)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            alert("Invalid name!");
            return false;
        }
    };
</script>
```

And here is where I called the function:

```
<form method="POST" action="confirmReservation.php" onSubmit="return validation()" name ="frm">
    <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
        <br><input type="text" id = "Fname" name="Fname" class="form-control"  placeholder="First Name" required>
    </div>
</form>
```

What might be the problem in my code?

Comment: What does not work exactly? What is the input that fails? http://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5BA-Za-z%5D*%2F

Comment: I suspect you missed the `$` to ensure a full string check: `/^[A-Za-z]*$/`.

Comment: If adding `$` is not yielding expected behavior, please provide a full fiddle to help you better.

Comment: BTW, since you appear to be validating a name, this article on "Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names", may be instructive... http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Oh, thanks! I can't believe I missed the $. Anyway, thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following using jquery:

```
var str = $('#Search').val();
if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(str) == false) {
   alert('Your search string contains illegal characters.');
}
```

Reference from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840143/jquery-check-if-special-characters-exists-in-string)