# How to check response json value has Hyphen '-' OR not in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting some value in JSON response. These some time contains hyphen '-'. So in javascript  '-' hyphen treated as a subtraction.

**JSON**

```
books": {
"red": "2008-17801",
"blue": "TERTERIAN-HAYK"
}
```

After getting these values I am putting into the array.

**LIKE**

> ["2008-17801"]
>    ["TERTERIAN-HAYK"]

But before the assigning I want to check value has hyphen'-' or not.
I checked one link, But it is checking all special characters.
[jQuery: Check if special characters exists in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840143/jquery-check-if-special-characters-exists-in-string).

I want to check only hyphen.

Comment: you get a string, you want a string, what is the problem?

Comment: `These some time contains hyphen '-'. So in javascript '-' hyphen treated as a subtraction.` that's true, but the hyphen is in a string in your case, so I don't see how that's an issue you need to worry about. Could you please edit the question to include the code which has this problem

Comment: what issue you are getting because of `-` there? i am unable to see any issue

Comment: You can use `indexOf` - `str.indexOf("-") != -1`

Comment: You can pass a regex to `match()`. See docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check the index of the `-` hyphen in the value of the `books` key.

```js
var data = {
  "books": {
  "red": "2008-17801",
  "blue": "TERTERIAN-HAYK"
  }
};

for(var book in data.books){
  if(data.books[book].indexOf('-') !== -1){
    console.log("There is hyphen in book "+book);
  }
}
```

Comment: Kindly upvote this question. If you want this question will exist

Comment: Because you have not told us why a hyphen is a problem at all

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace() to find if the value contains '-' and replace it with ' ' or anything else you would like before storing it in the array.

```
books["blue"].replace(/-/,' ');
```

or if you just want to find if '-' exists then you can use match() with regex.

Comment: from the comment above there shouldn't have any problem with `-` in the OP

Answer (score 0):

For getting **all values**?

```
var books = {
   "red": "2008-17801",
   "blue": "TERTERIAN-HAYK"
};
var allValues = Object.values( books );
```

For **checking if there is a *hyphen*** in any values?

```
var hasHypen = allValues.some ( s => s.indexOf( "-" ) != -1 );
```

Getting only **those values which have hyphen**?

```
var hyphenValues = allValues.filter( s => s.indexOf( "-" ) != -1 );
```